# Apache response time on custom chart on Stackdriver dashboard

Tags: stackdriver

We would like to have a line chart (or distribution) in our custom Stackdriver dashboard with the response time returned by the apache logs. Simple line chart, respone time or latency called by others coming from structured logs.

We setup our logging agent, added structured logs to fluentd as you can see on the image it's working on the log screen.

[image]

in the httpRequest we have the `latency`.

```
    httpRequest: {
  latency:  "0.081215s"   
  referer:  "-"   
  requestMethod:  "GET"   
  requestUrl:  "/v1/call/match-in?q=spdif&fields=&limit=200&ra..."   
  responseSize:  "636"   
  serverIp:  "3.89.69.139"   
  status:  200   
  userAgent:  "HTTPClient/1.0 (2.8.3, ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18))"   
 }
```

We tried creating a custom log metric by picking the field, and setting the expression as `([0-9.]+)s` to eliminate the ending 's'. Our values are in the 79ms  `0.079800s` not sure if we need to modify the bucket configuration.

[image]

But the chart is coming back empty:

[image]

How do we plot it as a line chart on a custom dashboard in Stackdriver?
Is there a way to plot an extracted time field from logs on the screen?

**Update 1:**

How can we actually check if we created a metric, that has too many time series? In the [Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/#troubleshooting) section there are three cases, but how do we verify them?

**Update 2:**

So we found that this doesn't work with values below 1. Like we had chart where we had numbers sub second, and looks like while it's between 0 and 1 it doesn't plot.

The below image clearly shows that while the latency was below 1 it didn't plot on the distribution start, and once it was more than 1 it was plotting on the right chart.

So based on these finding what is the real work around? What me missed?

[image]

here is our config:

[image]